# Is it possible to solve for two unknowns from one equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is it possible to solve for two unknowns using only one equation?

For example:

$x+3y=32$

Where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Thanks :)

Comment: $x,y \epsilon$ Natural Numbers?

Comment: You labeled the question as 'Diophantine-equations'. If $x,y$ don't have to be integers, this label makes no sense.

Comment: The set of solutions here is trivially $\{(32-3k,k) : k \in \Bbb Z\}$. For a more interesting example, you can consider the equation $2x+3y=32$. Note that such equations need not have solutions, for instance $2x + 6y = 31$ has none.

Comment: @ANerd: You should try squaring $x$ or $y$, that will be a challenging one. Something like $x^2+3y=32$ or $x+3y^2=32$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the original question 'Is it possible to solve for two variables related by single equation' is, YES!

Here is an example. Solve for two unknown real numbers $x$ and $y$ given a single equation 
$$x+\sqrt{y-1}=\sqrt[4]{1-y}$$
The only real solutions are $x=0,y=1$

---

**Solution** As $x,y$ are real numbers, either $y-1\ge0$ or  $1-y \le0.$

Assume that $y$ is strictly greater than $1$, then the LHS of the equation is a real number, whereas, the RHS will have non-zero complex part. A similar argument is also true when the value of $y$ is strictly less than $1$. Therefore, $y = 1$ is the only *possible* solution. Indeed, $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, is a solution, and the only one.

This may be considered as a hack, since apart from the equation, we have two constraints, i.e., $x$ and $y$ are Real. There are complex solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Not uniquely. You can solve for $x$ with $x = 32 - 3y$, and if you choose *any* $y$, you'll have an $x$ so the corresponding $(x, y)$ pair is a solution. Conversely, you can solve for y in terms of $x$, and then use (any? or just integer $x$ so that $y$ is an integer -- you filed this under "diophantine equations") $x$ choices to get $y$s for $(x, y)$ solution pairs.

Comment: Ah ha. So there can be like any possible number of solutions?

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions, in fact. One for each $y$ (or conversely, for each $x$ -- I see the comment you made.). When graphed, the solution set is a line in the plane (unless you really _do_ interpret it as a Diophantine equation, in which case it's just disconnected, isolated points.).