# Is it possible to solve for n unknowns from one equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations

We can solve for 2 unknowns from one equation: [Is it possible to solve for two unknowns from one equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336740/is-it-possible-to-solve-for-two-unknowns-from-one-equation)

But is it possible to solve for n unknowns from one equation?

Comment: Yes – sometimes – if the variables are required to be integers.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?

Comment: @Gae.S. Find all unknowns.

Comment: Why does this apply to the equation you've linked? I would say it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no and most single equations you encounter such as the linked $x+3y=32$ have multiple solutions.  But there are special cases.

If you are restricted to real numbers, then it is possible to transform simultaneous equations into a single equation.

For example $$x+y+z=6$$ $$x+2y+4z=17$$  $$3x+y+2z=11$$ have the unique solution $x=1,y=2,z=3$.  So too does the single equation $$(x+y+z-6)^2+(x+2y+4z-17)^2+(3x+y+2z-11)^2=0$$ which you could write as the less obvious $$21z^2+6y^2+11x^2+22yz+22xz+12xy-192z-102y-112x+446=0.$$

In a sense this is cheating, and there are an infinite number of solutions involving complex numbers.